# Adding class to element in php code

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I was given a piece of code to change the variable prices on my woocommerce store to display "from" before the price instead of a range of prices.

Here's the code in question:

```
<?php
function iconic_variable_price_format( $price, $product ) {

    $prefix = sprintf('%s: ', __('From', 'iconic'));

    $min_price_regular = $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true );
    $min_price_sale    = $product->get_variation_sale_price( 'min', true );
    $max_price = $product->get_variation_price( 'max', true );
    $min_price = $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true );

    $price = ( $min_price_sale == $min_price_regular ) ? 
        wc_price( $min_price_regular ) :
        '<del>' . wc_price( $min_price_regular ) . '</del>' . '<ins>' . wc_price( $min_price_sale ) . '</ins>';

    return ( $min_price == $max_price ) ? 
    $price : 
    sprintf('%s%s', $prefix, $price);

}
```

I'm looking for a way to add a class to the "from" text so I can add some CSS to change the color and font of the text but I'm not quite sure how to go about this and I don't want to mess with the function.php file too much and crash my site.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should carefully try it like this:

```
$prefix = '<span class="yourclass">' . sprintf('%s: ', __('From', 'iconic')) . '</span>';
```

Simply souround your `From` with a span with a custom class. I don't know what your __()-Function does but however: the result is a string and can be prepared with some additional markup.

It also should work like this (if you don't want your `:` to be included in your span:

```
$prefix = sprintf('<span class="yourclass">%s</span>: ', __('From', 'iconic'));
```